# Substitute capacitor voltage

Tags: capacitor

I have a circuit that is calling for a 400v capacitor to be used.  I only have 1000v available.  Can I susbtitute it and use the 1000v?

Comment: Capacitors rated for higher voltage usually have a higher [ESR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalent_series_resistance) which may or may not cause issues in your specific circuit. (Mostly not a problem for lower frequencies like 50/60Hz, but possibly for switching regulators or the like with several 100kHz.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The volt rating on a capacitor tells you at what voltage a capacitor breaks down.  When it breaks down the capacitor will burn through its dielectric causing a short.
There is nothing wrong with using a capacitor with a higher volt tolerance, just make sure the capacitor has the same capacitance and that both are polar or non-polar capacitors.

Answer (score 3):

Yes (assuming that all other parameters of the capacitor are the same or otherwise acceptable). The voltage rating of capacitors, called the [breakdown voltage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor#Breakdown_voltage), is the maximum voltage the capacitor can safely handle.